# Optimization of 2 unrelated table join

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, query-optimization, redundancy

I have an interface in which I will show a list of items from a **SQLite** database that each item can be one of two types: **SubItem1** and **SubItem2**. This database currently has three tables: **Items**, **SubItem1** and **SubItem2**.

The table **Items** contains the columns **SubItemId** and **Type** (0 - SubItem1; 2 - SubItem2)

**SubItem1** and **SubItem2** have different columns, but a good amount of them are the same.

So to use populate this list I am using a query like:

```
select i.*, s1.name, s2.name, s1.time, s2.place
from ITEMS i
left outer join sub1 s1 on (i.type = 0 and i.sub_id = s1.id)
left outer join sub2 s2 on (i.type = 1 and i.sub_id = s2.id)
```

I used these columns as an example, but I am selecting around 10 columns of each SubItem table.

With this query I am getting a lot of redundant rows. For instance, when the Type is SubItem1 for a particular Item, I will also be receiving the null columns of the table SubItem2

Is there a more efficient way to make this query?

Thanks.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help explain what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `COALESCE()` for the "same" columns :

```
select i.*, COALESCE(s1.name,s2.name) as name,
            COALESCE(s1.col1,s2.col2) as col2,
            ....
       s1.time, s2.place
from ITEMS i
left outer join sub1 s1 on (i.type = 0 and i.sub_id = s1.id)
left outer join sub2 s2 on (i.type = 1 and i.sub_id = s2.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select both types seperately with inner joins, and then combine both results with a [compound query](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#compound):

```
SELECT i.*, s.name, s.time, NULL AS place
FROM Items AS i
JOIN Sub1  AS s ON i.sub_id = s.id

UNION ALL

SELECT i.*, s.name, NULL,   s.place
FROM Items AS i
JOIN Sub2  AS s ON i.sub_id = s.id;
```

These are likely to be more efficient.

Comment: Thanks for opening my mind about using UNION. But the results showed a slight performance gain when not using UNION.